# Dados da requisição Ajax com AngularJS não estão chegando ao action method

Tags: ajax, angularjs, json, mvc

Sei que isso é muito básico, mas estou começando agora. Estou criando um cadastro de bairro, usando AngularJS, meu *back-end* é em C# com ASP.NET MVC. Meu metodo é chamado pela *view*, mas não recebe o JSON:

Esse é meu método salvar no `BairroController`:

```
//[HttpPost]
public dynamic save(string bairro)
{
    string user = "100";
    string pass = "a";
    int idEmp = 1;

    master = new ClassMaster();
    BairroModel BairroModel = new BairroModel();
    BairroDTO BairroDto = new BairroDTO();

    return BairroDto.save(BairroModel, user, pass, master.contexto, BairroModel.t0020_id_empresa = idEmp);
}
```

Esse é o Ajax salvar:

```
$scope.AddBairro = function (bairro) {
        $http.post("http://localhost:23714/Bairro/save", bairro).success(function (data) {
            //delete $scope.contatos;
            $scope.contaroForm.$setPristine();
            console.log(bairro);
        });                
    };
```

Problemas:

- Ao clicar em salvar, meu método é chamado, mas o parâmetro recebe `null`. Vejam o exemplo [aqui](http://prntscr.com/9hla4d).
- O método é chamado duas vezes e no console do firefox e é possível ver o que foi enviado, no caso, um `OPTIONS` e um `POST` (*Porquê?*), mas em nenhum dos casos o método captura o `json`.
- Nesse [link](http://prntscr.com/9hl8t9) é possível ver que o `json` foi realmente enviado, também é possível ver o `POST` e o `OPTIONS`.
- No Back-end, essa parte está comentada, se "descomentada", o método não é chamado.

Answer (score 1):

O "erro" ocorre porque o ASP.NET não está conseguindo fazer o *binding* dos dados da sua requisição, que é o que está contido no objeto `bairro` da parte em JavaScript do seu código, com o parâmetro `string bairro` do seu *action method* no C#.

O motivo para o *binding* não estar funcionando da maneira esperada é que no objeto enviado nenhuma das propriedades corresponde literalmente a "bairro", e é obrigatório que nos seus dados de envio algo corresponda a "bairro", pois quando chegar no servidor o ASP.NET irá analisar a requisição e extrair o que será utilizado para alimentar cada um dos parâmetros do *action method* alvo da requisição.

Pelo o que pude visualizar [nessa imagem](http://prntscr.com/9hl8t9) a variável `bairro` é um objeto e que no momento do envio da requisição contém várias propriedades, você provavelmente se confundiu nessa parte ao envia-lo por inteiro na requisição.

Então ao invés de enviar o objeto `bairro` por inteiro, extraia e envie apenas o dado sobre o bairro que está contido nele.

Analisando a imagem eu diria que a sua requisição poderia ficar da seguinte maneira:

```
$http({
    url: 'http://localhost:23714/Bairro/save',
    method: 'POST'
    params: { bairro: bairro['t0010_id_bairro'] }
})
.success(function (data) {
    $scope.contaroForm.$setPristine();
    console.log(bairro);
});
```

Comment: Mudei a assinatura do meu metodo do backend, ficou assim  public dynamic save(BairroModel bairro), mudei o tipo do bairro de string, para BairroModel, deu certo, como posso fazer para enviar mais um dado alem do que esta contida em data. EX: alem do q esta no data, quero enviar o numero 1.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro, o ASP.NET está esperando um POST no formato "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". adapte o seu $http para o seguinte:

Obs: Segundo recomendação do Angular, o Success foi descontinuado, use (THEN).

```
$http({
    url: 'http://localhost:23714/Bairro/save',
    method: 'POST',
    headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} ,
    data: { bairro: bairro }
}).then(function(){
     $scope.contaroForm.$setPristine();
     console.log(bairro);
})
```

Comment: Mudei a assinatura do meu metodo do backend, ficou assim  public dynamic save(BairroModel bairro), mudei o tipo do bairro de string, para BairroModel, deu certo, como posso fazer para enviar mais um dado alem do que esta contida em data. EX: alem do q esta no data, quero enviar o numero 1.

Comment: mais uma coisa, continua enviaando um OPTIONS e um Post, entao o metodo do back eh chamado duas vezes, pq será q isso esta acontecendo ?

Comment: Mas uma coisinha, só funciona se o tipo do parametro no back for BairroModel, teria como forçar aceitar um tipo string ?

Comment: Na realidade, ele vai aceitar qualquer valor que voce passar no formato de objeto.

Ou seja, se no seu BairroModel tiver uma propriedade "numero" e voce passar no data: `{ bairro: bairro, numero: 1 }`, seu backend receberá na propriedade do BairroModel.numero o valor 1

Comment: Eu preciso passar dados que nao estao na minha classe, queria colocar uma variavel do tipo string, mas nao aceita.

Comment: Voce precisa criar um objeto request específico que represente os parametros de entrada da sua fuynção. 

Em vez de usar o BairroModel, utilize uma nova classe SaveBairroRequest com as propriedades iguais à solicitação